# Disable button if value from API is zero Vue

Tags: jquery, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I have set of buttons getting live probability odds of an event for the user to select.
The buttons get data from an api every minutes.

[image: Here's how it looks]

I want to disable the button if the probability is zero, I have a class `suspended`, I want to add that class to the button.

This is the code I have so far.

**event.vue**

```
<div class="inply-coupon-odds-column">
 <span data-id="118584087800" class="bvs-button-multi-sport " clicksource="in-play">{{tgames.home_odd }}</span>
 <span data-id="118584088300"  class="bvs-button-multi-sport " clicksource="in-play">{{tgames.neutral_odd }}</span>
 <span data-id="118584088000"  class="bvs-button-multi-sport" clicksource="in-play">{{tgames.away_odd }}</span>
</div>
```

This the json response from the api call.

`{"neutral_odd":"0.00","home_odd":"1.38","away_odd":"2.75"}`

Will appreciate any solutions.

Comment: You do know that you don't have a single `<button>` in your code? A div (or span) is not a button. Think about using semantic HTML elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily achieve this by using Vue's class binding.

Class binding allows you to dynamically add / remove css classes from the dom element. Refer to the Official Docs
[Vue Class Binding](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes)

So in your case, you can try adding the `suspended` class by checking if the value is `0` like so

```
<div class="inply-coupon-odds-column">
    <span
      data-id="118584087800"
      class="bvs-button-multi-sport"
      :class="tgames.home_odd == 0 ? 'suspended' : ''"
      clicksource="in-play"
      >{{ tgames.home_odd }}</span
    >
    <span
      data-id="118584088300"
      class="bvs-button-multi-sport"
      :class="tgames.neutral_odd== 0 ? 'suspended' : ''"
      clicksource="in-play"
      >{{ tgames.neutral_odd }}</span
    >
    <span
      data-id="118584088000"
      class="bvs-button-multi-sport"
      :class="tgames.away_odd == 0 ? 'suspended' : ''"
      clicksource="in-play"
      >{{ tgames.away_odd }}</span
    >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement by using Dynamic [`HTML class binding`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes).

Just for demo, I am using iteration index as `data-id` nut you can replace it as per your requirement.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    tgames: {
      "neutral_odd":"0.00",
      "home_odd":"1.38",
      "away_odd":"2.75"
    }
  })
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.bvs-button-multi-sport {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

.suspended {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="inply-coupon-odds-column">
    <span
      v-for="(item, index) in Object.keys(tgames)"
      :key="index"
      :data-id="index"
      class="bvs-button-multi-sport"
      :class="!Number(tgames[item]) ? 'suspended' : ''"
      clicksource="in-play">
      {{ tgames[item] }}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```